# Stopping strstr before it runs into sigsegv

Tags: c, eof, segmentation-fault, file-writing, strstr

I have a large .xml file and need to pull specific bits out of it.
The things I need to pull out are encapsulated by a substring on either side.
I need to write the output to a file.

I'm searching for the starting sub and from there for the ending sub, then copying it and putting it out over fprintf.
I'm setting the start-pointer to the position of the last end pointer and it continues to search until it runs into the sigsegv.

I don't know how to stop the loop at the last occurrence of the substrings I'm searching for before it runs into the sigsegv.

An interesting problem I encountered is that if I output to stdout it prints everything I want to pull out and then breaks down.
If I want to write it to a file it doesn't write the same thing but breaks down before it finishes and in the process losing the last 37 lines of output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("C:/Users/entin/Desktop/IHP/Auswerte_Marko/TEMP/20190605204730250_S210D_PQ41701_TM2_TV2_MARK21Single_21Single.ega_rslt", "r");

    FILE *fw;
    fw = fopen("C:/Users/entin/Desktop/IHP/Auswerte_Marko/TEMP/t1.xml", "w");

    int f_length;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    f_length = ftell(fp);
    char file[f_length + 1];
    rewind(fp);
    fread(file, f_length, 1, fp);
    file[f_length] = 0; 



    const char *SPattern = "<MeasData "; // start of substring
    const char *EPattern = "</MeasData>"; // end of substring
    char *start, *end;
    char *target = NULL;

    if (start = strstr(file, SPattern)) { // search for start substring
        start += strlen(SPattern);
        if (end = strstr(start, EPattern)) { // search for end substring
            target = (char *) malloc(end - start + 1);
            memcpy(target, start, end - start); // copying content between start and end pointers
            target[end - start] = '\0';

            start = end; // setting new start to old end
        }
    }

    if (target) fprintf(stdout, "%s%s%s\n", SPattern, target, EPattern); // assembling everything back together

    free(target);


    //while (end <= EOF) { // repeating till end of file is reached
    while (end != NULL && *end != 0){ //EDIT from comments
        char *target = NULL;
        if (start = strstr(start, SPattern)) { // startig search from last end pointer
            start += strlen(SPattern);
            if (end = strstr(start, EPattern)) {
                target = (char *) malloc(end - start + 1);
                memcpy(target, start, end - start);
                target[end - start] = '\0';

                start = end;
            }
        }

        if (target) fprintf(stdout, "%s%s%s\n", SPattern, target, EPattern);

        free(target);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fw);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the files:

[Input File](https://pastebin.com/ZK3DptkS)

[Output to stdout that I want in a file](https://pastebin.com/iAHQiJNq)

[Output that I get when I write to a file](https://pastebin.com/iijPPAik)

(only the last lines of the output matter)

Comment: `while (end <= EOF)` This is not correct. `EOF` is a constant value to indicate end of file. It is not suitable for anything but check for equality. "Less or equal" does not make any sense. Also `end` is a pointer while `EOF` is an integer value. Did you intent to use `while(end != NULL && *end != 0)`?

Comment: `while (end <= EOF)`: this doen't make any sense: 1: you compare the _pointer_ `end` to `EOF` which is not a pointer; 2: you don't do any file operation within the while loop, so testing for `EOF` doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: This is completely true,... now I feel a bit more stupid to not catch that myself. Sadly after implementing it didn't solve the problem, the sigsegv still comes up with the same result.

Comment: Probably not the source of your problem, but: don't cast the result from `malloc()`, and do check it's not null.

Comment: @DerEntinator `*end != NULL` is wrong, `*end` is not a pointer, `end` is a pointer. Read again the first comment carefully.

Comment: If `start` doesn't get set to a non-`NULL` value, then `end` won't get set.  `end` has not been initialised before it is tested, so you have *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: `char file[f_length + 1];` is dangerous if `f_length` is more than will fit in the stack frame.  Oh, and don't ignore the return value of `fread()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane The weird thing is, that it can output the correct thing to stdout, but not to a file directly

Comment: So? It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's probably because `stdout` is line buffered and each `printf` is shown immediately on the terminal. OTOH the file can have a larger buffer and when your program stops crashing&burning the buffer is not flushed.

Comment: You could use `memmem()` instead of`strstr()`

Comment: Note that by using `fread` you can't guarantee that any sequence of characters is zero-terminated and thus is safe to apply `strstr`. If searching for text you should be using text-based input functions. Also you might miss a construction that starts in one data block and finishes in the next one.

Comment: @WeatherVane what do you mean by text-based input functions?

Comment: Properly parsing XML is **hard**.  See [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg) and [Why use an XML parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597239/why-use-an-xml-parser).

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve what I want to do e.g. pulling string between two stings out of the file and save it to a new one?

Comment: First rule: COMPILE WITH WARNINGS ENABLED.

Answer (score 0):

You should not check `end` but `start`.

```
while (end != NULL && *end != 0){ //EDIT from comments
    char *target = NULL;
    if (start = strstr(start, SPattern)) { // startig search from last end pointer
        start += strlen(SPattern);
        if (end = strstr(start, EPattern)) {
            target = (char *) malloc(end - start + 1);
            memcpy(target, start, end - start);
            target[end - start] = '\0';

            start = end;
        }
    }

    if (target) fprintf(stdout, "%s%s%s\n", SPattern, target, EPattern);

    free(target);
}
```

If you found the last element and search for the next one, `start` will be `NULL` and you won't enter the `if` block.
You don't change `end` in that case and call `strstr` again but now with `start == NULL`.

As far as I remember, `strstr` is not required to verify for valid pointers.

In your loop `end` will only ever become `NULL` if you find the start pattern but no end pattern. For a valid XML file this is rather unlikely to happen.

Comment: Note that `end` is *uninitialised* before first use. The OP's code still has plenty more wrong with it and there isn't one simple fix.